# Counting coefficients of linear congruences with prescribed solution

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Let $p$ be any prime. Let $m,n$ be positive integers with $\frac{3}{2}m < n < 2m$. Let $x$ be a positive integer with $1 \leq x < p^n$ and $\gcd(x,p)=1$.

Let $A = \{ a \in \mathbb{Z} : 1 \leq a < p^m, \, \gcd(a,p)=1 \}$ and $B = \{ b \in \mathbb{Z} : \frac{1}{2}p^m < b < p^m\}$.

Let $N$ be the number of $(a,b) \in A \times B$ that 
\begin{align}\tag{1} 
ax \equiv b \pmod{p^n}.
\end{align}

**Question.** Can it be shown that $N \leq C p^{2m-n}$ for all $m \geq m_0$?

Here $C$ and $m_0$ are constants that may depend on $p$, but not on anything else.

I'd be interested in anything better than the trivial bound $N \leq p^m$.

For reference the trivial bound $N \leq p^m$ is established as follows. For fixed $a \in A$, those $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ that satisfy (1) have the form $b=ax+kp^n$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $m<n$, there can be at most one such $b$ between $\frac{1}{2}p^m$ and $p^m$. (Note that if $n \leq m$, the same argument shows there can be at most $p^{m-n}$ such $b$ between $\frac{1}{2}p^m$ and $p^m$.)